# 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'object'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I enter this code:

```
buildSearchRes() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: searchResultsFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return cargandoCircular();
      }

      List<UserRes> searchRes = [];
      snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
        User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
        UserRes searchRes = UserRes(user);
        searchRes.add(searchRes);
      });
      return ListView(
        children: searchRes,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I get the error:

```
The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.
```

I'm already importing the `cloud_firestore` package.

I used to get a "'docs' can't be unconditionally access because the reciever can be null" error but adding a null check solved it.

Here's the rest of the code with another relevant pieces

```
class _BuscarPerfilState extends State<BuscarPerfil> {
 TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
 late Future<QuerySnapshot>? searchResultsFuture;

handleSearch(String query) {
 Future<QuerySnapshot> users = usersRef
  .where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query)
  .get(); //getDocuments();
 setState(() {
  searchResultsFuture = users;
 });}

AppBar buildSearchField() {
return AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  title: TextFormField(
    controller: searchController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Buscar un usuario...",
      filled: true,
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.account_box,
        size: 28.0,
      ),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: clearSearch,
      ),
    ),
    onFieldSubmitted: handleSearch,
  ),
);}



buildSearchResults() {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: searchResultsFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return cargandoCircular(); 
    }

    List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
    snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
      User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
      UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
      searchResults.add(searchResult);
    });
    return ListView(
      children: searchResults,
    );
  },
);}

@override
Widget build(context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.2),
  appBar: buildSearchField(),
  body:
      searchResultsFuture == null ? buildNoContent() : buildSearchResults(),
);}}
```

and for modeling user data I made this on another .dart document and imported it:

```
class User {
final String id;
final String username;
final String email;
final String photoUrl;
final String displayName;
final String bio;

User(
  {required this.id,
  required this.username,
  required this.email,
  required this.photoUrl,
  required this.displayName,
  required this.bio});

factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
return User(
  id: doc['id'],
  email: doc['email'],
  username: doc['username'],
  photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
  displayName: doc['displayName'],
  bio: doc['bio'],
);}}
```

Comment: Please provide the `searchResultsFuture` declaration associated Firestore query in full

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to review some more firebase examples and inspect the functions, return types and objects used.

**I will try to be brief about changes you can make:**

Using a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) (or a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)) is good. Even better is to make use of the [dart generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics).

e.g. `FutureBuilder<User>(...)`

When performing a Firestore query, you have to be aware of what you are getting. Are you getting a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querysnapshot) or a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot).

With a `QuerySnapshot`, you will get a bunch of [Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#documents) from the queried Firestore [collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections), where you can either get a `Stream` of `.snapshots()` ([example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections)) or get the latest using `.get()` ([example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections)).

Doing so gives you a `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` which has a `docs` getter and you can `.map()` this to another type or to a object of your choosing (see [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections)) where you will either use it in a `ListView` or do processing on it later.

---

With your example, I would suggest something similar to this:

```
class FirestoreService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<User>> searchUsersByDisplayName(String displayName) {
    const usersRef = _firebaseFirestore.collections(...);
    return usersRef.where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get().then((value) => value.docs.map(User.fromDocument).toList());
  }
}
```

Keep you queries separate from your views, else it gets muddled and you have a bunch of issues that will come your way.

Next, you widget state, use either late or null-safety, not both:

```
class _BuscarPerfilState extends State<BuscarPerfil> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  Future<List<User>>? searchResultsFuture;
  //...
```

Finally, user a `FutureBuilder<List<User>>` to retrieve your data and display it, for example (untested)

```
@override
Widget build(context) {
  FirestoreService _firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Theme
        .of(context)
        .primaryColor
        .withOpacity(0.2),
    appBar: buildSearchField(),
    body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(    // user futurebuilder or streambuilder
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // always check for errors
        if (!snapshot.hasError) { 
          return Text("Error retrieving results");
        }
      
        // depending on the connection state, you want to show different UI updates
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          // we are waiting on a connection, etc
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
          // we are grabbing data, this *can* continue on for a few seconds or we are done
          // display results as you wish
            return ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  User user = snapshot.data[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.displayName),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      foregroundImage: Image
                          .network(user.photoUrl)
                          .image,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(user.email),
                    onTap: () {
                      // go to profile page
                    },
                  )
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length);
        }
      },
      future: _firestoreService
          .searchUsersByDisplayName("query value here") // your Future query
      initialData: [], // empty data to begin with
    ),
  );
}
```